# Email follow-up for careers invitation has inconsistent expiration days

Tags: bug, jobs, email

I just wanted to point out a small bug in one of your system emails.

I was invited to join Stack Overflow Careers, and I received the following email (emphasis mine):

=======================

"We noticed you have not accepted our invitation to join Stack Overflow Careers. **Only 3 days remain** before it expires, and we’d love to have you. In case you missed the invitation, or never got it, here it is again:

...

But please act soon: **this invitation expires in 14 days**, so sign up now!"

=======================

So which is it? 3 days or 14 days?

I think somebody forgot to drop in a dynamic value in the second instance! Hope this helps!